# How to test dynamic page titles?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdom, react-testing-library, react-helmet

I'm using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) and change the documents page title depending on some conditions.

How can I test that behaviour with [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library)?

I tried something like

```
const { debug } = render(<TitleChangingComponent title="Test" />, {
    container: document.head,
});
debug();
```

But it just shows me an empty  in the debug output. Additionally I'm not 100% sure if this is related to react-testing-library in general or jsdom (I'm using Jest for my tests).

Comment: I think it has more to do with `react-helmet` and the way that it writes to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this years after it was asked, but just in case anyone else comes across this, I was able to do it in the following way:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  document.title = ''
})

test('Component changes title', () => {
  render(<Title title="Example" />)
  expect(document.title).toEqual("Example")
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't use `react-testing-library` for this.

I would test this in an E2E test e.g. with [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/title.html#Syntax).

```
cy.title().should('eq', '<your-title>')
```

Opinionated:

It is [best practice](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/unit-testing-react-components-aeda9a44aae2) to test your components and pure logic using unit tests and side effects as well as user interaction using end to end tests.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: I'd be more interested even in the why to why it doesn't work in jest